# Column Validation for Choice column

Tags: 2010, column, validation

I made a new required Choice column with these choices: "", "Yes", and "No".

Is it possible to use the built-in Sharepoint 2010 Column Validation to validate that the user chose either "Yes" or "No"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**

When you create your column there is this option:

> Require that this column contains information:

Mark it to *yes* so the item will always get a value for this column.